# Link present in XML should open in webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, webview, android-resources

I have code which displays Terms & Condition in app. In the first line i have a link. I want that link to be loaded in webview.

Following is the Fragment Code:

```
String[] tncList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tnc_text_array);

for(int i=0;i < tncList.length;i++)
{
    LinearLayout llItem=(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.terms_n_cond_fragment_layout, null);
    TextView txt= (TextView)llItem.findViewById(R.id.tncText);
    if(i == 0) {
        txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(tncList[i]));
        txt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    } else {
        txt.setText(tncList[i]);
    }
    tncTextLayout.addView(llItem);
}
```

Following is the String array from the resource file:

```
<string-array name="tnc_text_array">
    <item>Standard terms and condition apply To read click <![CDATA[<a href="example.com/termsandconditions">here</a>]]></item>
    <item>lorem ipsum</item>
    <item>lorem ispsum</item>
    <item>lorem ipsum</item>
</string-array>
```

By using the above code link is generated and user can click the link and open it in browser but it opens in mobile view, but I want it to open in desktop view.

I want it to either open in browser but in desktop view or in webview.

Comment: use android:autoLink="all" in xml textview

Answer (score 0):

you can take USER-AGENT in string :

```
String userAgent= Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36

WebView webView =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings.setuserAgentString(userAgent)
```

Comment: Isn' there any way I can set onclick listener to the href string and start an intent instead of using webview

Comment: you can load it on webview , intercept the very first url and then hide or destroy webview and then launch whatever intent you want to launch.

Comment: Can you provide a sample on how to do it.